# *ngIf auth user inverse

Tags: angular

I'm using the following code to show items as long as the user is authenticated.

```
<div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user" class="px-3 pt-3">
  <h4 class="font-weight-light">{{ user.displayName }}</h4>
</div>
```

Everything works well. But what happens if I want to place content when the user is not authenticated? what would be the opposite of this?

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
<mat-nav-list *ngIf="!auth.user | async as user">
  <a mat-list-item (click)="selected()" [routerLink]="['/']">
  <i class="material-icons-outlined mr-2">event</i>Login
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: Have you tried to put it into brackets `!(auth.user | async) as user`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the entire statement with [parenthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) to apply [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Description)(`!1) on the statement.

```
<mat-nav-list *ngIf="!(auth.user | async)">
  <a mat-list-item (click)="selected()" [routerLink]="['/']">
  <i class="material-icons-outlined mr-2">event</i>Login
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

---

In case you want to show them in the same place in your markup then use [else part](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else).

```
<div *ngIf="(auth.user | async) as user;else notauthorized" class="px-3 pt-3">
  <h4 class="font-weight-light">{{ user.displayName }}</h4>
</div>
<ng-template #notauthorized>
  <mat-nav-list *ngIf="!auth.user | async as user">
    <a mat-list-item (click)="selected()" [routerLink]="['/']">
    <i class="material-icons-outlined mr-2">event</i>Login
    </a>
  </mat-nav-list>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks, the first thing worked for me. I tried to use `ng-template` but it has conflict with the `mat-nav-list` that does not recognize the icons, well it's another topic but I wanted to explain why I did not use `ng-template`

Comment: @PacoZevallos try it like `<div *ngIf="(auth.user | async) as user;else notauthorized" class="px-3 pt-3">`